# Getting the avro schema from a library

Tags: java, maven, avro

I have many projects depending of Avro schemas and I would like to create a library that contains all of them.

Right now I have this library containing the .avsc files and from it I would like to be able to generate the avro java .class without generating the sources.

The problem is that I fail to see how to do that with the plugin :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/schemas/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *publish* the sources with Maven, but the plugin is not responsible for generating .class files; let the compiler-plugin do that.

Comment: I understand that, the issue is that I don't want to put my avro schemas in all my project....
But my bad, this question illustrate my real concern in a better way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997523/how-does-one-manage-its-avro-schemas-between-multiple-project