# How does one manage its avro schemas between multiple project?

Tags: avro

One of the main feature of Avro is to be a portable Schema between different project environment.

Currently I have an Avro schema that I use in 2 different project.

The issue I see is that I have to maintain the same schema in the 2 project. Basically I have the same project structure for both and a `schemas` folder containing .avsc files.
If I do an update in one I have to do the same in the other.

This good development practice and I would like to have those in a library so I can manage it as a dependency or something.

My first idea was to obtain the .class files in my project directly from the schema in the library and not having to generate the corresponding java files.

I fail to find something close to that so maybe it's simply not doable but also I don't believe that people using avro just copy past their schema in all their projects.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: (unrelated to Kafka) - Use a Schema Registry - https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one/ (multiple implementations of this exist). Or if you are only using JVM-based solutions, then upload your libraries to a shared Maven repo

Comment: I did a library, I targeted the version in 1.7 because my other/future project will at least be in java 1.7. It works but I feel like it doesn't respect the initial idea of using a portable format. What do you think ?

Comment: Java 1.7 or Avro `1.7.x`? Avro doesn't care about Java versions, AFAIK, although the latest Avro versions might only work with Java 8/11

Comment: Java 7 yes. What do you mean it doesn't care about java versions ? The generated class is compatible for all java versions ?

Comment: The generated sources should be (they are just basic POJO classes). The bytecode that is generated would depend on your compiler plugin versions

Comment: Yes ok so my maven-compiler-plugin is set to 7, so the avro POJO bytecode is in java 7 correct ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: OK nice, last question, do you think managing the avro event using bytecode through a shared lib is a good way ?

Comment: As long as you only use JVM-based projects, yes. It's the same pattern for any other SDK dependency that includes model classes